# access cross domain XML help JSONP without change in server side code

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

For last Couples of days, I am struggling a issue that ..I am accessing crossdomain XML  help of **JSONP**  and using below code but chrome browser  showing  **Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <**  ...
and cann't change server side code .

```
            $.ajax({  
                type:"GET",        
                url: StaticIpurl+'zpf_img_pages/userdetail.xml',
                data: {},
                dataType: "jsonp", 
                timeout: 200000,
                jsonp:"skywardDetails",
                success: function(result)
                { 
                        alert("success");

                 } 

            });
```

Plz help me ..

Comment: `StaticIpurl` what is this look like?

Comment: What do you see when visiting the URL directly in the browser?

Any server side syntax errors shouldn't affect your response, you should still get one.

This is more likely an issue with your code somewhere.

Just a note, you could also try:

    $.get ( url, function ( data ) {
        console.log(data);
    });

This should at least get you a response, from there you can debug further.

Comment: $.ajax({
     type: "POST",
        url: 'http://smartsap.smartusys.com:8007/sap(bD1lbiZjPTIwMA==)/bc/bsp/sap/zpf_img_pages/user_authorization.xml',
     data: {},
     dataType: "jsonp",
     processData: true,
     
     success: function (data, status, jqXHR) 
     {
       
        alert(data);
        
       
       
                        },error: function (xhr)
     {
      
      alert("Error in network connection. Please try later");
      }
    });